# Hibernate Criteria: find entity if any of its children's children have a specific property

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, criteria

I need to write a Criteria(or hql) to find a parent entity by a property of a child of its children entities. Here is my entities:

```
// The top level parent class
public class A {
    private Long id;
    private String someProperty;
    private B b;
    // and some other attributes...
}

// The second level parent class :)
public class B {
    private Long id;
    private List<C> cList;
    // and some other attributes...
}

public class C {
    private Long id;
    private B b;
    private List<D> dList;
    // Other attributes..
}

public class D {
    private Long id;
    private C c;
    private String importantAttribute;
    // Other attributes..
}
```

The question is the following. I want to get the list of `A` records if any of D records have the condition importantAttribute=="something" and if A have the condition someProperty=="somethingelse".

How can I write a hibernate criteria for this? All I could write until now is the following:

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(A.class, "a");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("a.someProperty", "somethingelse");

DetachedCriteria sub = DetachedCriteria.forClass(D.class, "d");
sub.add(Restrictions.eq("d.importantAttribute", "something"));
sub.setProjection(Projections.property("id"));
```

Then I gave up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(A.class, "a");
criteria.createAlias("a.b", "b");
criteria.createAlias("b.cList", "c");
criteria.createAlias("c.dList", "d");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("a.someProperty", "somethingelse");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("d.importantAttribute", "something");
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I'm not sure if it works correctly but at least it returns some results :) I need to test more, I think.

Comment: What if there is no object or list found against the a.b then it will not return even the parent object.

Comment: @ZahidKhan You can pass [`CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/CriteriaSpecification.html#LEFT_JOIN) as third parameter in `createAlias` method.

Comment: @PredragMaric method deprecated cr.createAlias("a.b", "ab", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN); hibernate 4.1.

Comment: @ZahidKhan You're right, but there is a replacement method. Use `cr.createAlias("a.b", "ab", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)`.

Comment: @PredragMaric it's not providing the desired result if the children have no entity regarding its parent. Infact it does'nt even return the parent. Have a look. `cr.add(Restrictions.ilike("student.student_city", "%"+city+"%")); cr.add(Restrictions.ilike("student.area_of_interest", "%"+areaOfInterest+"%")); cr.createAlias("student.careers", "studentCareer", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN); cr.add(Restrictions.ilike("studentCareer.instituti‌​on_name", "%"+University+"%"));` it does'nt retrun the student having no career but matching area of interest.

Answer (score 0):

If using HQL, something like this should work:

> ```
>   TypedQuery<A> query = em
>             .createQuery(
>                     "SELECT a FROM D d join fetch d.c c join fetch c.b b join fetch b.a a where a.someProperty = :someProperty and d. importantAttribute = :importantAttribute",
>                     A.class);
>     query.setParameter("someProperty", "somethingelse");
>     query.setParameter("importantAttribute", "something");
>     List<A> results = query.getResultList();
> ```

You'd need to have a "private A a;" link defined in your B class.

Comment: I can't add a field in B class.