# Hibernate Child Entity Condition Fetches Incorrect Child

Tags: hibernate, join, subquery, children

I have a parent entity (Company) and child entity (Employee) which are joined by one to many relationship by COMPANY_ID. Both Company and Employee has status column.

**CompanyEntity:**

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "company")
private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

@Column(name = "COMPANY_STATUS")
private String status;
```

**Employee Entity**

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "COMPANY_ID", nullable = false)
private Company company;

@Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_STATUS")
private String status;
```

Now I need to fetch all companies (whose status is in HIGH_PROFIT or LOW_PROFIT) and the employees (who status is PERMANENT). I have written a query as below.

**Query**

```
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Company.class);
    List<String> statusList = new ArrayList<>();
    statusList.add("HIGH_PROFIT");
    statusList.add("LOW_PROFIT");
    criteria.add(Restrictions.in("status", statusList)).createCriteria("employees").add(Restrictions.eq("status", "PERMANENT"));
    criteria.list();
```

On running the application, I get correct Company records, where as the Employee is not filtered by PERMANENT status, it contains all children with both CONTRACT and PERMANENT status.

On checking hibernate logs, I see 2 queries being executed

```
1. select this_.id as id1_3_2_, this_.COMPANY_NAME as COMPANY_NAME2_3_2_, this_.COMPANY_STATUS as COMPANY_STATUS3_3_2_, employ1_.id as id1_5_0_, employ1_.EMPLOYEE_STATUS as EMPLOYEE_STA4_5_0_ from COMPANY this_ inner join EMPLOYEE employ1_ on this_.id=employ1_.COMPANY_ID where this_.COMPANY_STATUS in (?, ?) and employ1_.EMPLOYEE_STATUS_ID=?

2. select employ0_.COMPANY_ID as COMPANY_ID5_5_0_, employ0_.id as id1_5_0_, employ0_.EMPLOYEE_STATUS as EMPLOYEE_STA4_5_1_ from EMPLOYEE employ0_ where employ0_.COMPANY_ID=?
```

I tried using `@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT) @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)` and `@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)` on employees variable of Company entity (like the code below), nothing worked.

```
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "company")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
```

I have also tried using alias on child entity and using the condition on child. It didn't work either.

Can some one help me in filtering the child with correct status?

Comment: For trial with alias did you used something similar as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29457393/1910582) ?

Comment: Yes, I did. And it gave me all records.

Answer (score 1):

You have received absolutely correct results:

Your `@OneToMany` mapping should not be filtered at all!

your query is transformed to the following sentence:  *fetch all CompanyEntities which have status of 'HIGH_PROFIT' and 'LOW_PROFIT' AND at least one employee of those has status 'PERMANENT'*

for you to have something like described you should switch either to service level (i.e.  `List<EmployeeEntity> fetchEmployeeInPermanentState(CompanyEntity entity) { /* write your query on EmployeeEntity here */ }` )

or you can define field on your CompanyEntity something like that:

```
@Filter(condition = "status = 'PERMANENT'")
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "company")
private List<Employee> permanentEmployees = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand this. I can't have filter hard coded in entity because I need to use the same entity for different conditions. Isn't it? In some other part of application, I need to fetch CONTRACT employees as well.

Comment: than you can define 3 more fields:   all employees,   contract employees, and permanent employees.   Or in case you are in JAVA8, you can create  one-liner to fetch specific kind of employee  `transient listEmployee(String  type) { return employees.stream().filter(o -> o.status.equals(type)).collect(Collectors.toList()); }`

Comment: That doesn't sound very efficient. I have similar code elsewhere in the application and it works absolutely fine. I am doing something wrong here and I am not able to find what it is.

Comment: Can I achieve this through HQL? Or native query?

Comment: nope.  unless you specify  flter on onetomany, your onetomany would not be filtered, because in general you are asking your entity manager to have multiple entitiies of the same entity, which fields are populated based on the query. It is not what the entitymanager have been created for. Imagine situation: you have 2 instances of Company with all employees and second only with LOW_PROFIT, values are stored in the same field.   How the entitymanager should persist state of this? which one should it trust? if it choses one instance over another, what to do with the left ?